# How to edit predefined questions to Facebook page in Messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-messenger

I am an admin of a Facebook business page and I've enabled "Help people start a conversation with your Page" feature. It shows frequently asked questions to make it easier for people to start a conversation:

[image: screen shot]

Question: is it possible to edit these predefined questions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Go to "Settings" of your FB page, then click "Messaging".

Scroll to "Help people start a conversation with your Page" and click change.

[image: screen shot]

The questions are there and you can edit/delete/add.

Comment: This may have changed. There is no longer a "Help people start a conversation" under settings.