# How to edit predefined questions to Facebook Page in Facebook Chat plugin (Messenger)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

There is already [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117517/how-to-edit-predefined-questions-to-facebook-page-in-messenger) question, but the answer is outdated and in current Facebook settings I see no way of changing the predefined questions.

So how to do it?

In my Inbox -> Chat plugin settings I have no Frequently asked questions defined (I even disabled the feature - [screenshot from settings](https://ibb.co/d4fmZj8)) and the default questions asking about store location, opening hours and such still show.

When I add one frequently asked question, this question appears nowhere. It doesn't replace the default questions.

So what is going on? How can I remove and change the default Facebook chat plugin questions?

Answer (score 0):

did you find solution please?
After switch of my FB page to new environment I can't modify or delete predefined questions.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/153174)